# Get vector from exprTk as output

Tags: c++, exprtk

I can't seem to get a vector output from exprTk. I figure it should be relatively simple but in the manual I can only find how to input a vector and not how to output one.

What I currently have is the following:

```
typedef double T; // numeric type (float, double, mpfr etc...)
typedef exprtk::symbol_table<T> symbol_table_t;
typedef exprtk::expression<T>     expression_t;
typedef exprtk::parser<T>             parser_t;

std::string expression_string = "var z[2] := { x, y };";

T x = T(5.3);
T y = T(2.3);
std::vector<T> z;

symbol_table_t symbol_table;
symbol_table.add_variable("x", x);
symbol_table.add_variable("y", y);
symbol_table.add_vector("z", z);

expression_t expression;
expression.register_symbol_table(symbol_table);

//Check if expression is valid
parser_t parser;
if (!parser.compile(expression_string, expression))
{
    printf("Compilation error...\n");
    return;
}

T result = expression.value();
std::cout << result << std::endl;     \\returns: 5.3 as expected the first element of vector z.
std::cout << z[0] << std::endl;       \\Crashes the program
```

What I want as output is just the vector z.
How do I do this, or what am I doing wrong?

Comment: I don't know how `exprtk` works but it might expect the vector to be the correct size already.  If you use `std::vector<T> z(2);`, does it still crash?  If not, does it give the correct values in `z`?

Comment: If I initialise the vector I get the  "Compilation error..." message during the parser expression check.

Comment: Hmm.  Welp that wasn't it.  Hopefully someone else will be able to help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found a method that does work, but hopefully there is a simpler 'one-line' method

```
std::string expression_string = "var w[2] := { x, y }; z := w";
```

This creates an expression local vector `w` ([SECTION 13 - VARIABLE, VECTOR & STRING DEFINITION]), and then assigns the value to `z`

As @NathanOliver mentioned, `std::vector<T> z(2);` is also needed

---

`"var z[2] := { x, y };"` doesn't work as it is an illegal redefinition of the `z` variable, due to the use of the `var` statement.

Note that `"z := {x, y}"` will also not work as this does not appear to be a valid assignment expression for a vector

---

Output (with debug enabled):

```
prev[var] --> curr[var]
prev[var] --> curr[w]
prev[2] --> curr[]]
prev[x] --> curr[,]
prev[y] --> curr[}]
parse_define_vector_statement() - INFO - Added new local vector: w[2]
activate_side_effect() - caller: parse_define_vector_statement()
parse_corpus(00) Subexpr: var w[2] := { x, y };
parse_corpus(00) - Side effect present: true
-------------------------------------------------
prev[z] --> curr[:=]
prev[:=] --> curr[w]
prev[w] --> curr[]
activate_side_effect() - caller: lodge_assignment()
parse_corpus(01) Subexpr: z := w
parse_corpus(01) - Side effect present: true
-------------------------------------------------
5.3
5.3
```

Comment: Thanks that works, I will keep it open for a little bit longer, hopping for the 'one-line' method. If that is not forthcoming I will accept this answer.

Answer (score 3):

As per **Section 20 - Expression Return Values** of the ***readme***, One can immediately exit an expression returning any number of variables of any type simply by using the return statement.

The example provided in the documentation is as follows:

```
std::string expression_string =
   " if (x < y)                                   "
   "   return [x + 1,'return-call 1'];            "
   " else if (x > y)                              "
   "   return [y / 2, y + 1, 'return-call 2'];    "
   " else if (equal(x,y))                         "
   "   x + y;                                     "
   " return [x, y, x + y, x - y, 'return-call 3'] ";

typedef exprtk::symbol_table<double> symbol_table_t;
typedef exprtk::expression<double>     expression_t;
typedef exprtk::parser<double>             parser_t;

symbol_table_t symbol_table;
expression_t   expression;
parser_t       parser;

double x = 0;
double y = 0;

symbol_table.add_variable("x",x);
symbol_table.add_variable("y",y);

expression.register_symbol_table(symbol_table);

parser.compile(expression_string,expression);

T result = expression.value();

if (expression.results().count())
{
   typedef exprtk::results_context<T> results_context_t;
   typedef typename results_context_t::type_store_t type_t;
   typedef typename type_t::scalar_view scalar_t;
   typedef typename type_t::vector_view vector_t;
   typedef typename type_t::string_view string_t;

   const results_context_t& results = expression.results();

   for (std::size_t i = 0; i < results.count(); ++i)
   {
      type_t t = results[i];

      switch (t.type)
      {
         case type_t::e_scalar : ...
                                 break;

         case type_t::e_vector : ...
                                 break;

         case type_t::e_string : ...
                                 break;

         default               : continue;
      }
}
```

---

**Note1:** 
Your expression will become:

```
var z[2] := { x, y }; return [z];
```

**Note2:** 
In order to have your "one-line" method you could write a simple *free function* that wraps the boiler plate code after the conditional and extracts the vector of your choosing *(i'th result given it's of vector type)* from the **`results`** list.

```
template <typename T>
bool get_vector(const std::size_t index, 
                const results_context_t& results,
                std::vector<T>& v)
{
   ...
}
```

Comment: Is there a way to have this in a generic way? My users really want to be able to do: 
`var vec[N] := {..stuff..}; vec` and get the same exact result than if they did `var vec[N] := { ..stuff.. }; return [ v[0], v[1], ... ];`

Comment: @Jean-MichaëlCelerier those two return statements are different, one is returning a vector whereas the other is returning N scalar values.

Comment: isn't a sequence of N scalar values the definition of a vector of dimension N?

Comment: @Jean-MichaëlCelerier In your situation wouldn't the better approach be to simply  return the vector like:  `return [vec]`